# Hdd Showing Only few Minutes in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I have SSD, HDD installed and HDD in the caddy, SSD has an os that boots the system. when I turn on the laptop I get all the partitions in the hard drive and SSD after 1 minute it only shows SSD. any help is much appreciated

[image: Only SSD SHOWING]
[image: All PARTITIONS SHOWING]

Comment: What is the caddy?

Comment: In computer hardware, a caddy refers to a container used to hold some medium, such as a CD-ROM. If the medium is a hard disk drive, the caddy is also referred to as a disk enclosure. Its functionality is similar to that of the 3.5" floppy disk's jacket.

Comment: What is **your** caddy? My hard drives do not have 3.5" floppy disk jackets

Comment: no I replaced my cdrom with caddy

Comment: is that so you can plug a hard drive into the computer from the front?

Comment: can you show a picture of it?

Comment: https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/empty-laptop-hdd-caddy-hard-drive-caddy-attached-to-cd-optical-drive-bay-to-make-dual-storage-one-laptop-concept-empty-125295843.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140454/discussion-between-mrshakila-and-user253751).